# Restoring site collection on different sql server version

Tags: 2013, migration, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I am planning to restore a SP2013 site collection from a farm running on MSSQL 2008r2 into a different farm which runs on 2012 MSSQL.

Is it possible?

Is there any issue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sharepoint version is the same on the destination than I don't see any issue.

When you restore the db is n sql  2012 8it is kind of upgrade for database.

Make sure destination sharepoint suppers the sql server.